# React Native Vscode TypeScript debugger stepping extremely slow

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've got a few projects that use TypeScript (some with React, some with React Native), but for some reason, a particular React Native project started to get *extremely* slow while debugging. Here's an actual step over recording (I've reduced frame rate of GIF, but it's the same time that it takes to wait until stepping to next line):

[image]

The project doesn't have anything super large or fancy, and Vscode is perfectly okay with debugging TypeScript blazingly fast on my other projects. It used to debug this one just as fast too. I haven't worked on this project for a few weeks, meanwhile updated many dependencies, Vscode, even macOS itself, coded for a while without debugging, and only now I realized it got slower *at some point*, but I have no idea where.

What might be going on?
(TypeScript 3.8.3, React Native 0.62.2, React 16.12.0, Vscode 1.43.2, macOS 10.15.4)

Comment: Did you check the date/time settings on the simulator/device? I have seen slow debugging due to the clock settings. (Simulator should be ahead of the computer)

Comment: @nipuna777 they are exactly the same. date-time drift happens with Android emulator, I've never seen such in iOS Simulator.

Comment: Could it be a consecuence of React Native and his hibrid like project structure? I have never used the step by step debugger because the build time is usually super slow.

Comment: @JuanDavidRamirezVillegas the weird part is everything works fine with other projects, _including_ React Native + TypeScript (if you mean that by hybrid). The problem is specific to project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with the problem for months, upgrading to TypeScript 4.0.2 and Vscode 1.48.2 today solved the problem. TypeScript and TSX stepping is just instantaneous again as it should be.